# Where does it specify that you need 000-default.conf in apache2.4.x

Tags: apache-2.4, linuxmint

I deleted this file 000-default.conf and put my own in instead. In the default apache2.conf  line 219

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

however when I restart apache

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

all I have is:

```
my-pc sites-available # ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6437 Jan  7  2014 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  271 Aug 29 22:12 mysite.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you deleted `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` but left the symlink at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, which is now a dead link.  Is that the case?

Comment: all I see in nautilus is default.ssl and mysite.conf

Comment: Use `ls -l` on the command line instead of nautilus?

Comment: don't see anything.

Comment: Run `ls -l` in `sites-enabled` (the directory that is being loaded from, not in `sites-available` as you have in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have removed `000-default.conf` files.But symlink is still available.

---

So you need to disable it.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Comment: you have to disable the site 000-default like it's mentioned in the other comment. In order to make your site work with apache configuration you need to enable it using   a2ensite mysite.conf . This will create a symbolic link in sites-enabled directory and apache will be able to load the virtual host.